# Is it possible to simulate GitHub context when calling a workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I have an existing workflow that runs tests, builds, and saves artifacts. Let's call it BuildFlow. Until now it's triggered by GitHub events - push, PR, release. For instance - when the release manager manually creates a new release, it's triggered.

Now I want to automate the release process. I'm going to create a ReleaseFlow workflow, which creates a new release. I'm looking for a way to integrate my new workflow with the existing one.

I see a few ways to do that, but I don't like them:

- use PAT into ReleaseFlow, so BuildFlow will be triggered by 'release' event.

  - Pro: I don't need to modify BuildFlow.
  - Cons: ReleaseFlow and GitHub GIU don't know BuildFlow progress and status
- use 'workflow_call'.

  - Pro: ReleaseFlow and GUI know BuildFlow status.
  - Cons: I have to modify BuildFlow code in many places - to use the proper commit/tag and so on.
- I know about 'repository_dispatch', benc-uk/workflow-dispatch - but they don't provide visibility

Ideal integration, in my opinion, will simulate GitHub context when calling a workflow, so I won't need to modify BuildFlow.

Is there a better way that I missed?